# Is there a lightweight OctoPi multi-camera implementation?

Tags: octoprint, octopi, camera

I've seen and read many videos and articles about a multicamera setup in OctoPi. Most of them including [Setting up multiple webcams in OctoPi the right way](https://community.octoprint.org/t/setting-up-multiple-webcams-in-octopi-the-right-way/32669) describe:

> However, watch your CPU usage as streaming can be quite resource-intensive.

Other guides note a maximum amount of cameras for the Pi. However, in my case, I want to simply manually switch to some cameras for another view and maybe only have one camera used for time lapses, which is simple snapshotting, not streaming.

I was wondering why there is a camera limit at all because cameras can simply be disabled when not used, so at most there would be one active at the time. Is there currently such implementation available compatible with OctoPrint and for example OctoApp? Because switching cameras off and on only when used could save a lot of resources which is much more resource efficient, especially in a resource-limited environment like a Raspberry Pi (OctiPi).